# React - is it always a good idea to have api function in the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component that gets used in 3 different places.  That component is very simple..

It's a input file component with a button. So user chooses the file and then clicks `upload`. Let's call this `childComponent`.  `upload` button when clicked, should upload the image to some API service with `axios`.  Now, as I said, this component does get used in 3 different places, which means I really don't know if it's a good idea to put api call in the parent.

Way 1. I know that it's generally a good practice to do api calls and actual FINAL handling of data in the parent. So in Way 1, user clicks `upload`, childComponent sends the file to the parent component, and parent does the api call.

Way 2. uploading to the api happens in the childComponent directly. This might bring an issue where we need to show the loader while the file is uploading and loader needs to be in parent. If that's the case, in the upload function, we got `setLoading(true)` and after api is done, `setLoading(false)`. `setLoading is a prop function.

I am not so keen on WAY 1, because then since this `childComponent` is used in 3 places, then in all parents of those 3 places, I have to repeat the logic of file upload...

Question: What do you do in this case and why ? I believe this is not an opinion based answer. If so, I'd still appreciate your inputs anyway.

Comment: Honestly, I'd place the API calls in a separate service file that is injected using dependency injection in the child components. The service could also include Subjects (see rxjs) or other variables for the API call status loader components

Comment: Are you using any state management library like redux, and if not do you have any idea of working with React context api with the use of hooks

Comment: Yeah, basically I have a utils file which calls the api and in the child component, I just import that function and use it directly. @LoveenDyall .

Comment: How can this be achieved better with `context api` , I don't have much experience in react. just started. I don't use redux