# react state function does it get created on every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I understand why `useCallback` is good. It doesn't create new functions if deps didn't change.

Is the same thing true for `state` functions ?

for example:

```
// parent component
const [val, setVal] = useState<boolean>(false);

<childComponent 
    :setVal={setVal}
/>
```

Now if parent component re-renders for some other reason than `val` field, `setVal` function will be created again, which will cause `childComponent` to re-render again for no obvious reasons. Is this true ? and if so, I guess, there's no way to work around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's fine to pass `setVal`. `useState` takes care of returning the same `setVal` instance on every render cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. if you have time, could you possibly look into this as well ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560658/react-is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-have-api-function-in-the-parent