# why useCallback is the same instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
 let [myValue, setValue]  = useState(30);

  let k = {};
  let z = {};

  const a = useCallback(() => {
    return myValue + 10;
  }, [myValue]
  )

  k = a;

  setTimeout(() => {
    setValue(60)
  }, 2000)
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    z = a;
    console.log(z == k);
  }, 4000)
```

This is my react code.

It seems like in the final `setTimeout`, `z` is `k` and prints `true`. I don't understand why..

in 2 secs, I change `myValue` which should cause `re-rendering` which should cause calling `useCallback` and returning different instance of `a`. Any idea why it's printing `true` in the last `setTimeout` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myValue` isn't a prop or a state value, it is a straight-forward local variable.

Assigning a new value to a variable doesn't trigger a rerender.

---

If it *did* trigger a rerender then you would call `setTimeout` twice more and each rendering of the component would have its **own** set of `k`, `z`, etc which the functions you pass to `setTimeout` would close over.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili — Well, yes. See the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: you mention: `if it did trigger a rerender` . So I guess it for sure rerenders, it's just each re-render has its own set of `z,k` and they are always equal to each other. Am I understanding this correctly ? I wanted to test if `useCallback` really returns the same function if no deps have changed. How can I test this by myself ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili yeah, it really returns the same instance. If you still don't believe, use global variables to store the value between rerenders and compare them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.. This is one of my last questions, remaining if you don't mind.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560658/react-is-it-always-a-good-idea-to-have-api-function-in-the-parent